# Plugin update, is a deactivation and activation done?

Tags: plugins

When a plugin is being updated via the automatic updater, is that plugin deactivated and then re activated when the plugin update is finished?

Also is a maintenance file created during theme and plugin updates, or only during core updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code of *wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php*

**Single plugin update:**

```
add_filter('upgrader_pre_install', array(&$this, 'deactivate_plugin_before_upgrade'), 10, 2);

add_filter('upgrader_clear_destination', array(&$this, 'delete_old_plugin'), 10, 4);
```

It'll deactivate the plugin before upgrade and you need to re-activate it manually after upgrade.

No maintenance file generated

**Bulk Pluigns Update**

```
add_filter('upgrader_clear_destination', array(&$this, 'delete_old_plugin'), 10, 4);


// Only start maintenance mode if running in Multisite OR the plugin is in use
```

No deactivation before upgrade. The plugin status will be as what it was. So, if it is activated now, it'll still be activated after upgrade.

And maintenance file will be generated if running in Multisite OR the plugin is in use.

I urge you to read the source code yourself in case if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's interesting, why are bulk treated differently than single?